# Disable Style in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

Is there anyway to turn off a style programatically?

As an example, I have a style that is linked to all textboxes

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

I would like to add some code to actually stop the style elements being used, so basically reverting back to the default control style.

I need a way to make a switch in my styles, so I can switch between Windows default style and my custom style through C# code.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

**Working Solution**

[Switching between themes in WPF](http://sa.ndeep.me/post/switching-between-themes-in-wpf)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For setting the style to default,

In XAML use,

```
<TextBox Style="{x:Null}" />
```

In C# use,

```
myTextBox.Style = null;
```

---

If style needs to be set as null for multiple resources, see **CodeNaked's** response.

---

In code Behind I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
Style myStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["myStyleName"];
    
public void SetDefaultStyle()
{
    if(Application.Current.Resources.Contains(typeof(TextBox)))
        Application.Current.Resources.Remove(typeof(TextBox));
    
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBox),      
                                      new Style() { TargetType = typeof(TextBox) });
}
    
public void SetCustomStyle()
{
    if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains(typeof(TextBox)))
        Application.Current.Resources.Remove(typeof(TextBox));
    
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBox), 
                                      myStyle);
}
```

Comment: How about if I were to change the style for all TextBoxes, and then be able to change it back to the styles used before again?

Comment: I don't think that suits what I need. atm I have one style which is targeted for all textboxes. I would like to be able to revert every textbox in the program away from the custom style I set and make it null so it can be back to the Windows Default. And also have C# code to change it back to my custom style. any possibility? Thanks

Comment: Is this something that you are doing for testing your app in default style or is it for implementing a 'switch to default style' feature in your app? If it is testing, then simply set the null style in XAML & remove it later.

Comment: It is a way to switch the styles in my application to the default and back to the custom if the user wishes. So I need a switch on this end

Comment: Thanks I get an error when using the SetDefault: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'  Key being added: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'

Comment: I wish it did, but it didn't have any change whatsoever. :(

Comment: Again no change, I don't really know why it's not doing it, is it because I have my style in the app.xaml perhaps?

Comment: I think, yes. Where did you use the above methods & are the styles simply included as resources in app.xaml?

Comment: Yes the styles are included in the app.xaml resources, the code was used in a different xaml.cs file

Comment: There goes one more attempt. Now check if it works for the whole app styling.

Comment: I have actually tested the above code. It works just fine, even if the styles are defined anywhere as resources in the app.xaml.

Comment: I will check it very soon. I'll give you feedback and Mark the answer as correct if it's done. If not I'm sure I've got enough info there to trial and error

Comment: @Sandeep - If you define the TextBox implicit Style in your Window.Resources, then it would still override any TextBox implicit Style you have in your Application.Resources. You may want to try this is a small simple project to see it in action. There must be something else that you are omitting that is the actual cause of the issue.

Comment: @loxxy - I'm not sure if you saw my answer before making your first edit. If you did it is common courtesy to give credit. Your statement "The above if included in resources of say a Window, will apply default style to every TextBox inside the Window" is incorrect. The default Style is always applied. An implicit Style is just applied *in addition to* the default Style, unless OverridesDefaultStyle is set to true. Nor does the an implicit Style "set all textbox styles to null".

Comment: @loxxy it all works now as it should, i've also just added a key identifier and manually entered code for all control types to use the style instead of the XAML doing it.

Comment: @CodeNaked I am really sorry. I did not notice that you had added an answer. I was simply, responding to the comments (where I made more 10-12 edits which finally lead to the above. Nevertheless you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 23):

You could inject a blank Style that would take precedence over your other Style. Like so:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" />
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the example above, only the Grid's implicit Style would be applied to TextBoxes in the Grid. You could even add this to the Grid programmatically, something like:

```
this.grid.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBox), new Style() { TargetType = typeof(TextBox) });
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the answer has been accepted, but i want to add my solution which works awesome in the following scenario:

- One main application using mahapps.metro
- additional project imported from the main application with no reference to mahapps.metro, it is imported as a plugin (loading compiled .dll on the fly)
- using the < ToolBar> re-styles everything to null therefore the mahapps.metro styles are not being applied to items inside the toolbar.
- usercontrol is used to provide custom controls to the main application.

in the user control root set the resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" />
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

then the toolbar code can be the following

```
                <ToolBar>
                    Block Template:
                    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"/>
                    <Button Content="Generate!" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
                </ToolBar>
```

this successfully applies the main application style to the controls inside the < ToolBar>

Answer (score 1):

In Xaml, you can override this by setting a style explicitly.  In code-behind, you can also set the style explicitly.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource SomeOtherStyle}"/>

myTextBox.Style = Application.Resources["SomeOtherStyle"];
```