# override MahApps combobox with a custom style

Tags: wpf, combobox, mahapps.metro

### Issue

---

I am using MahApps in my WPF application but when i add a control it uses the MahApps control. I want to use the default combobox and style that.

Is there a way i can just use default combobox and style that the way i need it?

### Code

---

I have tried adding `Style={x:Null}` but the issue with this is that i cannot then add my style `Background="Transparent"` to that control.

I have also tried adding a custom style, but the issue with this is that it removed the drop down icon from the control.

```
        <Style x:Key="Combobox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#858585" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#ec122c"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Style in WPF XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946112/disable-style-in-wpf-xaml)

Answer (score 4):

You can save the original style before you define the MahApps styles e.g. at the `App.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- save the default Combobox style -->
        <Style x:Key="DefaultComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" />
        <Style x:Key="DefaultComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxItemStyle}" />
        </Style>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you can inherited from this style and create another style or use it directly.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <TextBlock Text="Original ComboBox Style" Margin="5" />
    <ComboBox Width="200" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="MahApps ComboBox Style" Margin="5" />
    <ComboBox Width="200">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

</StackPanel>
```

This screenshot shows the original ComboBox style (using the Win10 theme).

[image]

And here is the MahApps style.

[image]

Hope this helps.